# Repetir el bucle

Tags: java, html, eclipse

Entrada
El programa recibirá, por la entrada estándar, un conjunto de casos de prueba, cada uno en una línea. Cada caso de prueba estará compuesto de un número de vivienda. Se garantiza que nunca será mayor que 1.000.
El  último caso, que no deberá procesarse, será el número 0.

Salida
Para cada caso de prueba el programa escribir ́a “IZQUIERDA” (sin las comillas) si la vivienda está situada a la izquierda de la calle, y “DERECHA” si está a la derecha.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal_5_9 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    /*Para cada caso de prueba el programa escribir ́a “IZQUIERDA” (sin las comillas) si la vivienda 
    está situada a la izquierda de la calle, y “DERECHA” si est ́a a la derecha.*/

    //variables
    int num=0;
    int contador=0;

    for(int i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++);
    System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la casa entre 0 y 1.000: ");
    num=teclado.nextInt();

     if(num>1000) {
            System.out.println("El numero tiene que ser menor que 1000, inserte otro numero");
            num=teclado.nextInt();}
    
    if(num<1000 && num%2==0) {
        System.out.println("El edificio esta a la Derecha");}   
        
    if(num<1000 && num%2!=0) {
        System.out.println("El edificio esta a la Izquierda");} 
        
        
    }

}
```

Yo creo que la estructura del programa esta lista, lo que me falta es que se repita para poder poner varios numeros y me digan si estan a la derecha o a la izquierda

Comment: Entiendo, pero para responderte bien necesito saber que criterio necesitas para parar de pedir numeros ( escribir -1 , "salir", o algo asi ).

Comment: Hola, para que pare de pedir numero hay que poner 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución a este problema sería cambiando el bucle `for` por un `while`. Gobernando ese `while` estaría una nueva variable booleana "repetir", que se inicializa a `true` .
Dentro del bucle, añadiría otro `if` para cubrir el caso de `num==0` , cambiando del valor de "repetir" y saliendo del bucle con un `continue`.

Sería algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * Para cada caso de prueba el programa escribir ́a “IZQUIERDA” (sin las
     * comillas) si la vivienda está situada a la izquierda de la calle, y “DERECHA”
     * si est ́a a la derecha.
     */

    // variables
    int num = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    boolean repetir = true;
    while (repetir) {

        System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la casa entre 0 y 1.000: ");
        num = teclado.nextInt();

        if (num == 0) {
            repetir = false;
            System.out.println("Adios!");
            continue;
        }
        if (num > 1000) {
            System.out.println("El numero tiene que ser menor que 1000, inserte otro numero");
            num = teclado.nextInt();
        }

        if (num < 1000 && num % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("El edificio esta a la Derecha");
        }

        if (num < 1000 && num % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("El edificio esta a la Izquierda");
        }

    }
}
```

Se podría evitar el `continue` ,  si excluyes el cero del resto de ifs para que no se procesen. Y se podría evitar la variable "repetir", sustituyendo el `continue` por un `break` ( y dejando el bucle como `while(true)` ) , pero la versión que propongo creo que es la más sencilla de entender/implementar.

Saludos !!

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en tu código lo tienes mal estructurado. El bucle for:
`for(int i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++);` -> tienes un ';' tras el for y nada de lo que viene a continuación está entre las llaves, por lo que nada se va a repetir.

Te recomendaría que desde ya apliques las java code conventions: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Para que tu código sea mucho más legible y estructurado. Aunque no son de obligatorio cumplimiento te ayudará a evitar errores de este tipo.

Para el caso que te aplica, te recomendaría mejor sustituir tu bucle for por un while (como bien te indican en el comentario anterior), de forma que cuando se cumpla la condición establecida (planta 0) termine el programa y, mientras continúe procesando dato.

Un saludo!